# jquery datatable search is not working just reloading and shows any result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I have a problem the search input is not working in jquery datatable, when I write some data it just reloads and doesn't do anything, and when I add entities it just doesn't reload.
This is my HTML code

```
 <table id="producttable " class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{l s='ID' mod='newmodule'}</th>
            <th>{l s='Product name' mod='newmodule'}</th>
            <th>{l s='Price' mod='newmodule'}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

this is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $(".table").DataTable({
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'searching': true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        'iDisplayLength': 5,
        'ajax': {
            'url': mp_ajax + '?action=ptable'
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id_product"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "price"}
        ],

    });
    $('.form-control').on('keyup', function () {
        table.search(this.value).draw();
    });
})
```

and there is PHP code but it works fine and I don`t have question about it.

Comment: yeah, thanks I saw about it and fixed

Comment: Check console for errors.  It could be that when you "write data" the whole page does a form post/reload and your js code does nothing (due to the error).  Or your `.form-control` doesn't have that class, or is loaded dynamically: after the doc.ready has run (this is the most likely).  Try changing `$(".form-control").on("keyup", function` to $(document).on("keyup", ".form-control", funtion`

Comment: I did try your variant of a way to fix my error and get the same result.And yeah I don`t have any error during I write date in search input

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Try using `input` in event binding, instead of `keyup`, as it will be beneficial for searching while copy pasting any data. Also remove the extra spacing in the table id. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Okay, thank you I did what you told to me, and everything works fine,thanks

Comment: That was my pleasure ;)